# Xquery returning list of maps rather than map

Tags: xpath, xquery, marklogic

I have the following function

```
declare private function local:get-map() as map:map*
{
    let $map := map:map()

    for $chart in xdmp:directory("/charts/")
        for $panel in $chart/delphi:chart/delphi:panels/delphi:panel
            for $dataline in $panel/delphi:datalines/delphi:dataline
                let $datasetHref := $dataline/delphi:link[@rel="dataset"]/@href 
                let $axisId := $dataline/delphi:dimensions/delphi:dimension[@field="y"]/@axis
                let $label := $panel/delphi:axes[@dimension="y"]/delphi:axis[@id=$axisId]/@label

                let $l := map:get ($map, $datasetHref)
                let $updateMap := if (fn:exists ($l)) then () else map:put ($map, $datasetHref, $label)

                return $map
};
```

I have been forced to declare the return type as `map:map*` because for some reason $map is an array of maps rather than a map.  The array contains many items, where each item contains the same map that I need.  So when I call this method I use take the first item.  Problem is this is not exactly elegant.  What I don't understand is why do I get multiple copies of the same map in an array.  I expected the code to return a single map.  How do I rewrite this to solve the issue?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's returning a sequence of maps, because each iteration of each of the "for"s returns it. Try this:

```
declare private function local:get-map() as map:map
{
  let $map := map:map()
  let $populate := 
    for $chart in xdmp:directory("/charts/")
    for $panel in $chart/delphi:chart/delphi:panels/delphi:panel
    for $dataline in $panel/delphi:datalines/delphi:dataline
    let $datasetHref := $dataline/delphi:link[@rel="dataset"]/@href 
    let $axisId := $dataline/delphi:dimensions/delphi:dimension[@field="y"]/@axis
    let $label := $panel/delphi:axes[@dimension="y"]/delphi:axis[@id=$axisId]/@label

    let $l := map:get ($map, $datasetHref)
    return if (fn:exists ($l)) then () else map:put ($map, $datasetHref, $label)

  return $map
};
```

This does the FLWOR statement in its own let, then returns the map.

Comment: This didn't work - it gave me the same issue.  Are you sure this is the solution?

Comment: Looks like you accepted the answer after this comment; does that mean you have it working now? The key is that the "return $map" is not part of the FLWOR with the for statements.